# Can I put a table valued function in a DataSourceAttribute?

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, datasource, user-defined-functions

Microsoft's `[DataSource(...)]` lets you put in a name of a table as a string to supply data to your unit test. I want to generate data with dynamic sql, and believe the best way to do this would be with a tvf, though I'm open to suggestions.  When I try:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", CONN, "tvf(10)", DataAccessMethod.Sequential]
```

I get an invalid object name 'tvf(10)' error. I can only assume Microsoft is putting [brackets] around my tvf(10) and totally killing its tvf-ness. Is there a way around this?

Edit: I have successfully generated a dynamic view in [ClassInitialize], but I feel that a tvf would be a cleaner approach if MS would just allow it.

Comment: Use `tvf` as you use a table that is `select col1, col2 from tvf(10) t`.

Comment: unfortunately it's not me writing the sql, it's microsoft through that attribute, and microsoft isn't writing the sql properly for a tvf. @AlexKudryashev